# Docker cannot build my R package - fails to install R dependencies

Tags: r, docker, cran, renv

Previously functional R projects of mine suddenly cannot be compiled to Docker images. Issue is possibly related to recent updates to the Docker hub R base image `https://github.com/rstudio/r-docker`

Snippet of the Dockerfile to build my R API solution:

```
FROM rstudio/r-base:4.1.0-focal
COPY api/renv.lock /package/api/renv.lock
RUN R -e "utils::install.packages(c('renv'), repo='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"
RUN R -e "renv::consent(provided=TRUE)"
RUN R -e "renv::restore(lockfile = '/package/api/renv.lock', \
repos = c(RSPM = 'https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/all/latest'))"
```

Specifically, R packages `sodium`, `gert`, `odbc` and possibly others cannot be properly installed and break the Docker build operation:

> 523.7 - Installing zip ...                            OK [installed binary and cached in 0.41s]
> 524.1 - Installing gert ...                           FAILED
> 524.5 /opt/R/4.1.3/lib/R/bin/R --vanilla -s -f '/tmp/RtmpViVzDK/renv-install-7407e83e3'
> 524.5 ================================================================================
> 524.5
> 524.5 Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gert’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
> 524.5  unable to load shared object '/opt/R/4.1.3/lib/R/library/.renv/1/gert/libs/gert.so':
> 524.5   libgit2.so.28: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> 524.5 Execution halted
> 524.5
> 524.5 Error: error testing if 'gert' can be loaded [error code 1]

Everything worked fine 3 weeks ago and there are no code changes on my end. Any ideas?

**EDIT / Temporary fix**: Adding the following to the Dockerfile makes the image build - but why are these cryptic dependencies suddenly missing from the base image? This was an iterative troubleshooting process to secure the installation of R packages `sodium`, `odbc`, `gert`, `lava` and `waldo`.

```
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing -qq && apt-get install -y -q \
       libsodium-dev \
       libssl-dev \
       libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
       libgit2-dev \
       unixodbc-dev\
       unixodbc \
       odbcinst1debian2 \
       odbcinst \
    && apt-get clean \
    && apt-get purge \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

Comment: looks like you might be missing some dependencies. gert requires libgit2 to work so you can try adding `RUN apt-get install -y libgit2`

Comment: `odbc` also requires dependencies `apt-get install -y unixodbc unixodbc-dev`.

Comment: You can rely on alternate Docker containers as the base, for example [rocker/r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u) allows you to run `install.packages(c("sodium", "gert", "odbc"))` and it will install pre-compiled Ubuntu 22.04 binaries for you along with _all_ their required libraries.  Easy, fast, reliable.

Comment: For reference, `rstudio/r-base` is intended to be used as a "base" image, upon which other required tools would be installed for other Docker images. If you want a "batteries-included" Docker image, you should consider e.g. https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/rstudio.